# Trouble Making logs persistant on Google cloud kubernetes engine for airflow using airflow community chart

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, persistent-volume-claims

I have been trying for 2 weeks to deploys airflow on google kubernetes engine.
I managed to do that and deploys my dags through a docker image on dockerhub "repo/imagename"
using the KubernetesExecutor.

I tried to make logs persistent but can not do that.
I trie every steps in  [link](https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/docs/faq/monitoring/log-persistence.md#option-1---persistent-volume-claim) using

- Option 1 Persistent Volume Claim  ( user or chat managed one )
- or Option 3 - Pod Volumes. (persistentVolumeClaim, nfs, host )

But i am not able to do that.

Using kubernetes pods, the pvc has to be ReadWriteMany and gke doesnt handle that.
They say you have to create a filestore disk which is size 1T ( and costly )
i dont want to use that.
I have been struggling for two weeks, can you guys check this out please ?
these a re my files :

values.yaml

```
########################################
## CONFIG | Airflow Configs
########################################
airflow:
  ## if we use legacy 1.10 airflow commands
  legacyCommands: false

  ## configs for the airflow container image
  ## [FAQ] https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/docs/faq/configuration/airflow-version.md
  image:
    repository: repo/imagename
    tag: '1.0.6'
    # pullSecret: "airflow-docker-config"

  ## the airflow executor type to use
  executor: KubernetesExecutor

  ## the fernet encryption key (sets `AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY`)
  ## [FAQ] https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/docs/faq/security/set-fernet-key.md
  ## [WARNING] change from default value to ensure security
  fernetKey: "7T512UXSSmBOkpWimFHIVb8jK6lfmSAvx4mO6Arehnc="

  ## the secret_key for flask (sets `AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__SECRET_KEY`)
  ## [FAQ] https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/docs/faq/security/set-webserver-secret-key.md
  ## [WARNING] change from default value to ensure security
  webserverSecretKey: "THIS IS UNSAFE!"

  ## environment variables for airflow configs
  ## [FAQ] https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/docs/faq/configuration/airflow-configs.md
  config:
    AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__EXPOSE_CONFIG: "False"
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: "False"
    # AIRFLOW__LOGGING__REMOTE_LOGGING: "True"
    # AIRFLOW__LOGGING__REMOTE_BASE_LOG_FOLDER: "gs://ftm_dev_airflow_tmp/airflow/logs"
    # AIRFLOW__LOGGING__REMOTE_LOG_CONN_ID: "storage"

  ## a list of users to create
  ## [FAQ] https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/docs/faq/security/airflow-users.md
  users:
    - username: admin
      password: admin
      role: Admin
      email: admin@example.com
      firstName: admin
      lastName: admin

  ## a list airflow connections to create
  ## [FAQ] https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/docs/faq/dags/airflow-connections.md
  connections:
    - id: Eli_Lilly_SA
      type: google_cloud_platform
      description: my Eli_Lilly_SA connection
      extra: |
        {
          "extra__google_cloud_platform__key_path": "/opt/airflow/secrets/gcp-keyfile/keyfile.json",
          "extra__google_cloud_platform__num_retries": 5
        }
    - id: lundbeck_amulet_SA
      type: google_cloud_platform
      description: my lundbeck_amulet_SA connection
      extra: |
        {
          "extra__google_cloud_platform__key_path": "/opt/airflow/secrets/lundbeck/lundbeck18331.json",
          "extra__google_cloud_platform__num_retries": 5
        }
    - id: pfizer_x9001262_SA
      type: google_cloud_platform
      description: my lundbeck_amulet_SA connection
      extra: |
        {
          "extra__google_cloud_platform__key_path": "/opt/airflow/secrets/pfizer/pfizer.json",
          "extra__google_cloud_platform__num_retries": 5
        }
    # - id: storage
    #   type: google_cloud_platform
    #   description: my google cloud storage connection
    #   extra: |
    #     {
    #       "extra__google_cloud_platform__key_path": "/opt/airflow/secrets/pfizer/pfizer.json",
    #       "extra__google_cloud_platform__num_retries": 5
    #     }
  ## a list airflow variables to create
  ## [FAQ] https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/docs/faq/dags/airflow-variables.md
  variables: 
    - key: "env"
      value: "local"  

  ## a list airflow pools to create
  ## [FAQ] https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/docs/faq/dags/airflow-pools.md
  pools: []

  ## extra pip packages to install in airflow Pods
  ## [FAQ] https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/docs/faq/configuration/extra-python-packages.md
  ## [WARNING] this feature is not recommended for production use, see docs
  extraPipPackages: []

  ## extra environment variables for the airflow Pods
  ## [FAQ] https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/docs/faq/kubernetes/mount-environment-variables.md
  extraEnv: []

  ## extra VolumeMounts for the airflow Pods
  ## [FAQ] https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/docs/faq/kubernetes/mount-persistent-volumes.md
  ## [FAQ] https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/docs/faq/kubernetes/mount-files.md
  extraVolumeMounts: 
    - name: gcp-keyfile
      mountPath: /opt/airflow/secrets/gcp-keyfile
      readOnly: true
    - name: lundbeck
      mountPath: /opt/airflow/secrets/lundbeck
      readOnly: true
    - name: pfizer
      mountPath: /opt/airflow/secrets/pfizer
      readOnly: true
    ## spec: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.20/#volumemount-v1-core
    # - name: logs-volume
    #   mountPath: /opt/airflow/logs

  ## extra Volumes for the airflow Pods
  ## [FAQ] https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/docs/faq/kubernetes/mount-persistent-volumes.md
  ## [FAQ] https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/docs/faq/kubernetes/mount-files.md
  extraVolumes: 
    - name: gcp-keyfile
      secret:
        secretName: elililly-gcp-connection-secret
    - name: lundbeck
      secret:
        secretName: lundbeck-gcp-connection-secret
    - name: pfizer
      secret:
        secretName: pfizer-gcp-connection-secret
    # - name: logs-volume
    #   nfs:
    #     path: /pvc
    #     server: nfs-service.storage.svc.cluster.local
    # - name: logs-volume
    #   persistentVolumeClaim:
    #     claimName: nfs-pvc
    # - name: logs-volume
    #   nfs:
    #     path: /airflowVolume/logs
    #     server: 10.0.0.2
    # - name: storage
    #   secret:
    #     secretName: storage-gcp-connection-secret

  ## configs generating the `pod_template.yaml` file for `AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__POD_TEMPLATE_FILE`
  ## [NOTE] the `dags.gitSync` values will create a git-sync init-container in the pod
  ## [NOTE] the `airflow.extraPipPackages` will NOT be installed
  kubernetesPodTemplate:

    ## the full content of the pod-template file (as a string)
    ## [NOTE] all other `kubernetesPodTemplate.*` are disabled when this is set
    stringOverride: ""

    ## resource requests/limits for the Pod template "base" container
    ## [SPEC] https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.20/#resourcerequirements-v1-core
    resources: {}

    ## extra pip packages to install in the Pod template
    ## [FAQ] https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/docs/faq/configuration/extra-python-packages.md
    ## [WARNING] this feature is not recommended for production use, see docs
    extraPipPackages: []

    ## extra VolumeMounts for the Pod template
    ## [FAQ] https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/docs/faq/kubernetes/mount-persistent-volumes.md
    ## [FAQ] https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/docs/faq/kubernetes/mount-files.md
    extraVolumeMounts: []

    ## extra Volumes for the Pod template
    ## [FAQ] https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/docs/faq/kubernetes/mount-persistent-volumes.md
    ## [FAQ] https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/docs/faq/kubernetes/mount-files.md
    extraVolumes: []

###################################
## COMPONENT | Airflow Scheduler
###################################
scheduler:
  ## the number of scheduler Pods to run
  replicas: 1

  ## resource requests/limits for the scheduler Pods
  ## [SPEC] https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.20/#resourcerequirements-v1-core
  resources: {}

  ## configs for the log-cleanup sidecar of the scheduler
  ## [FAQ] https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/docs/faq/monitoring/log-cleanup.md
  logCleanup:
    enabled: false
    retentionMinutes: 21600
    ## the number of seconds between each check for files to delete
    intervalSeconds: 900

  ## configs for the scheduler Pods' liveness probe
  ## [FAQ] https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/docs/faq/monitoring/scheduler-liveness-probe.md
  livenessProbe:
    enabled: true
    ## number of seconds to wait after a scheduler container starts before running its first probe
    ## NOTE: schedulers take a few seconds to actually start
    initialDelaySeconds: 10

    ## number of seconds to wait between each probe
    periodSeconds: 30

    ## maximum number of seconds that a probe can take before timing out
    ## WARNING: if your database is very slow, you may need to increase this value to prevent invalid scheduler restarts
    timeoutSeconds: 60


    ## maximum number of consecutive probe failures, after which the scheduler will be restarted
    ## NOTE: a "failure" could be any of:
    ##  1. the probe takes more than `timeoutSeconds`
    ##  2. the probe detects the scheduler as "unhealthy"
    ##  3. the probe "task creation check" fails
    failureThreshold: 5


    ## configs for an additional check that ensures tasks are being created by the scheduler
    ## [FAQ] https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/docs/faq/monitoring/scheduler-liveness-probe.md
    taskCreationCheck:
      ## if the task creation check is enabled
      enabled: true
      ## the maximum number of seconds since the start_date of the most recent LocalTaskJob
      ## WARNING: must be AT LEAST equal to your shortest DAG schedule_interval
      ## WARNING: DummyOperator tasks will NOT be seen by this probe
      thresholdSeconds: 300
      ## minimum number of seconds the scheduler must have run before the task creation check begins
      ## WARNING: must be long enough for the scheduler to boot and create a task
      ##
      schedulerAgeBeforeCheck: 180

###################################
## COMPONENT | Airflow Webserver
###################################
web:
  ## the number of web Pods to run
  replicas: 1

  ## resource requests/limits for the web Pods
  ## [SPEC] https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.20/#resourcerequirements-v1-core
  resources: {}

  ## configs for the Service of the web Pods
  service:
    type: ClusterIP
    externalPort: 8080

  ## configs generating the `webserver_config.py` file
  ## [FAQ] https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/docs/faq/configuration/airflow-configs.md#webserver_configpy
  webserverConfig:
    ## the full content of the `webserver_config.py` file (as a string)
    stringOverride: |
      from airflow import configuration as conf
      from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_DB
      
      # the SQLAlchemy connection string
      SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = conf.get("core", "SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN")
      
      # use embedded DB for auth
      AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_DB

    ## the name of a Secret containing a `webserver_config.py` key
    existingSecret: ""

###################################
## COMPONENT | Airflow Workers
###################################
workers:
  ## if the airflow workers StatefulSet should be deployed
  enabled: false

###################################
## COMPONENT | Triggerer
###################################
triggerer:
  ## if the airflow triggerer should be deployed
  enabled: true

  ## the number of triggerer Pods to run
  replicas: 1

  ## resource requests/limits for the triggerer Pods
  ## [SPEC] https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.20/#resourcerequirements-v1-core
  resources: {}

  ## maximum number of triggers each triggerer will run at once (sets `AIRFLOW__TRIGGERER__DEFAULT_CAPACITY`)
  capacity: 1000

###################################
## COMPONENT | Flower
###################################
flower:
  ## if the airflow flower UI should be deployed
  enabled: false

###################################
## CONFIG | Airflow Logs
###################################
logs:
  ## the airflow logs folder
  path: /opt/airflow/logs

  ## configs for the logs PVC
  ## [FAQ] https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/docs/faq/monitoring/log-persistence.md
  persistence:
    enabled: true
    # storageClass: ""
    # size: 100Gi
    existingClaim: nfs-pvc

###################################
## CONFIG | Airflow DAGs
###################################
dags:
  ## the airflow dags folder
  path: /opt/airflow/dags

  ## configs for the dags PVC
  ## [FAQ] https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/docs/faq/dags/load-dag-definitions.md
  persistence:
    enabled: false

  ## configs for the git-sync sidecar
  ## [FAQ] https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/docs/faq/dags/load-dag-definitions.md
  gitSync:
    enabled: false

###################################
## CONFIG | Kubernetes Ingress
###################################
ingress:
  ## if we should deploy Ingress resources
  ## [FAQ] https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/docs/faq/kubernetes/ingress.md
  enabled: false

###################################
## CONFIG | Kubernetes ServiceAccount
###################################
serviceAccount:
  ## if a Kubernetes ServiceAccount is created
  create: true

  ## the name of the ServiceAccount
  name: ""

  ## annotations for the ServiceAccount
  annotations: {}

###################################
## CONFIG | Kubernetes Extra Manifests
###################################

## a list of extra Kubernetes manifests that will be deployed alongside the chart
## [FAQ] https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/docs/faq/kubernetes/extra-manifests.md
extraManifests: []

###################################
## DATABASE | PgBouncer
###################################
pgbouncer:
  ## if the pgbouncer Deployment is created
  ## [FAQ] https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/docs/faq/database/pgbouncer.md
  enabled: true

  ## resource requests/limits for the pgbouncer Pods
  ## [SPEC] https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.20/#resourcerequirements-v1-core
  resources: {}

  ## sets pgbouncer config: `auth_type`
  authType: md5

###################################
## DATABASE | Embedded Postgres
###################################
postgresql:
  ## if the `stable/postgresql` chart is used
  ## [FAQ] https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/docs/faq/database/embedded-database.md
  ## [WARNING] the embedded Postgres is NOT SUITABLE for production deployments of Airflow
  ## [WARNING] consider using an external database with `externalDatabase.*`
  enabled: true

  ## configs for the PVC of postgresql
  persistence:
    enabled: true
    storageClass: ""
    size: 4Gi

###################################
## DATABASE | External Database
###################################
externalDatabase:
  ## the type of external database
  ## [FAQ] https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/docs/faq/database/external-database.md
  type: postgres
  # password: "o8IfZBpOa+dYc''`"
  # # password: jCLB~\D_3g-j8Hte
  # user: airflow
  # host: "34.22.250.22"
  # port: 5432
  # database: airflow

###################################
## DATABASE | Embedded Redis
###################################
redis:
  ## if the `stable/redis` chart is used
  enabled: false

###################################
## DATABASE | External Redis
###################################
externalRedis:
  ## the host of the external redis
  ## [FAQ] https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/docs/faq/database/external-redis.md
  host: localhost
```

pv.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nfs-pv
  namespace: storage
  labels:
    app: nfs-data
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    server: "nfs-service.storage.svc.cluster.local"
    path: "/pvc" # "pvc" folder must exist in "/exports" directory of NFS server
```

pvc.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: nfs-pvc
  namespace: storage
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: ""
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nfs-data
```

i created an nfs server and a service for it :

nfs.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nfs-server
  namespace: storage
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nfs-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nfs-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nfs-server
        image: k8s.gcr.io/volume-nfs:0.8
        ports:
        - name: nfs
          containerPort: 2049
        - name: mountd
          containerPort: 20048
        - name: rpcbind
          containerPort: 111
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
        - name: storage
          mountPath: /exports
      volumes:
      - name: storage
        hostPath:
          path: /var/lib/data/nfs # store all data in "/var/lib/data/nfs" directory of the node where it is running
          type: DirectoryOrCreate # if the directory does not exist then create it



---


apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nfs-service
  namespace: storage
spec:
  ports:
  - name: nfs
    port: 2049
  - name: mountd
    port: 20048
  - name: rpcbind
    port: 111
  selector:
    app: nfs-server # must match with the label of NFS pod
```

I createds some pods to use that pvc and it works, all file create create in the mounted path of that pod, will be directed to that pvc.

test-pod.yaml

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nfs-pod-pvc
  namespace: storage
spec:
  containers:
  - name: busybox
    image: busybox
    command:
    - sleep
    - "3600"
    volumeMounts:
    - name: data
      mountPath: /demo/data
  volumes:
  - name: data
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: nfs-pvc
```

Comment: We had quite a bit of troubles with community edition helm chart, finally switched to official helm chart for Airflow 2.4.1, which we customized for our requirements and got it working finally after some trouble in the beginning. 

https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/apache-airflow/airflow - the link.